# Google map area/neighbourhood selection

Tags: google-maps

In some websites (example: http://www.dubizzle.com/) I have seen an excellent Google Map feature which allows the user to select a neighborhood/region from a dropdown and the Google map shown just below the drop downwill zoom to that area and highlighted the region using a polygon.. Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this functionality.. The screen shot of this is given below

[image]

Thanks
Anz

Answer (score 2):

They are likely using a [polyline overlay](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polylines) ([example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple.html)), or a [KML layer](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#KMLLayers) ([example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml.html)).

Could you provide a link to the page that you grabbed the screenshot from?

Comment: @Matt.. thank you for the reply.. you can see the map page only if you register and try to post an ad in the above website..  so I guess they will have polylines coordinates stored for each neighbourhood and highlighting it based on the dropdown selection, right?

Comment: @Anz: well, that makes me feel less incompetent :) ...to answer your question: **yes**, you nailed it.